# Ubuntu Server (20:04) command reboot with '-p' option does not work as expected

Tags: command-line, shutdown, reboot

About the `reboot` command, according with:

- [focal (8) reboot.8.gz](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/reboot.8.html)

Indicates:

```
  -p, --poweroff
           Power-off the machine, regardless of which one of the three commands is invoked.
```

practically same message with `reboot --help`

Therefore with `reboot` it reboots the OS as expected and with `reboot -p` happens the same - it is **not** expected. Was expected to *power-off/shutdown* the machine instead. Just in case it happens with `sudo` too.

Was is missing or wrong?

**Note** just in case - It is being tested through `Virtual Box`

Comment: What would you expect when the Virtual Machine halts? The hypervisor, knowing the VM "should" be running, restarts the VM, Ubuntu boots, ...

Comment: I expected the same behavior as `poweroff` command - it shutdown the OS and the VM is closed.

Comment: Have you tried the other option `halt` just to test? It should halt while keeping the power on.

Comment: I tried `sudo reboot --halt` (btw `sudo` is mandatory) and it goes to shutdown and remains/stays with the `Starting Halt...` message and nothing more. I am assuming this command does not work well through Virtual Box

Comment: Why not try using shutdown? `$ shutdown -P

Comment: There is most-likely a few of them that don't "work as expected" reboot, halt, shutdown, poweroff - are all the same and various linux OSes are probably going to interpret/process the arguments differently. You are better off just using the name with the function you want to "do" as the command and simply have that passed to systemd, rather than hope systemd interprets the arguments in order. (.... or feel free to tailor the code)